# equivalent percentile_cont function in apache spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark environment. I have dataset with column names as follows:

---

### user_id, Date_time, order_quantity

I want to calculate the 90th percentile of order_quantity for each user_id.

If it were to be sql, I would have used the following query:

```
%sql 
SELECT user_id, PERCENTILE_CONT ( 0.9 ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)
```

However, spark doesn't have the built in support for using the percentile_cont function.

Any suggestions on how I can implement this in spark on the above dataset?
please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for PERCENTILE_DISC (0.9) which will return the discrete order_quantity closest to percentile 0.9 (without interpolation). 
The idea is to calculate PERCENT_RANK, substract 0.9 and calculate Absolute value, then take the minimal value: 

`%sql 
WITH temp1 AS (
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    ABS(PERCENTILE_RANK ()  OVER 
        (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_quantity) -0.9) AS perc_90_temp
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    FIRST_VALUE(order_quantity) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY perc_90_temp) AS perc_disc_90
FROM 
   temp1;`

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with a similar issue too. I worked in SAP HANA and then I moved to Spark SQL on Databricks. I have migrated the following SAP HANA query:

```sql
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ITEM_ID, 
    LOCATION_ID, 
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VENTAS) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID) AS P95Y, 
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRECIO) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID) AS MEDIAN_PRECIO 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

to

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  ITEM_ID,
  LOCATION_ID,
  PERCENTILE(VENTAS,0.8) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID) AS P95Y,
  PERCENTILE(PRECIO,0.5) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID) AS MEDIAN_PRECIO
FROM
    delta.`MY_TABLE`
```

In your particular case it should be as follows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, PERCENTILE(order_quantity,0.9) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)
```

I hope this helps.